# Bass model of diffusion

Tags: anylogic

I simulated the diffusion model Bass "Distribution of a New Product".

For examples:

[image]
And this is the result of the model:

[image]
1) How to find AdEffectiveness and AdoptionFraction values in which AdoptionRate values are maximized at the end of the simulation process?

2) How to find AdEffectiveness and AdoptionFraction values in which AdoptionRate values are maximized at the beginning of the simulation process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your question is not what you really want to answer, and this is why:

So the adoption rate should be:

```
PotentialAdopters * AdEfectiveness
+ Adopters * ContactRate * AdptionFraction * PotentialAdopters / 
(PotentialAdopters + Adopters )
```

**For question 1:**

If we assume that your model has no time limit and runs forever, the adoption rate in time t=infinity will ALWAYS be zero. This is because there is nothing that increases the number of potential users so the potential users will always decrease no matter what (unless AdEfectiveness=0 in which case the adoption rate will be zero anyways) until they reach zero and the Adopters reach 100,000.

**For question 2**:

To maximize adoption rate at the beginning of the simulation you have to maximize the formula above:
Maximize:
100,000 * AdEfectiveness
    + 0 * ContactRate * AdoptionFraction * PotentialAdopters / 
    (PotentialAdopters + Adopters )

So you have to maximize 100,000 * AdEfectiveness
Which will obviously be maximized with the maximum value AdoptionFromAd can take (maybe infinity), and AdoptionFraction doesn't matter